# Hide/show cells in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have create a UITableView in IB. This view contains 5 sections and every section some cells. The first cell in some sections gives the option to the end user to show/hide the rest of the cells that belongs to the same section.

My code so far:

```
import UIKit

class SettingsVC: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var showCallForwardSwitch: UISwitch?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func toggleValueChanged(sender: UISwitch) {

        if showCallForwardSwitch!.on {
            println("switch is on")
        } else {
            println("switch is off")
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }  
}
```

So there is only an IBOutlet and an IBAction. I can get the event via the toogleValueChanged func, however I don't know what to do from now on. Which methods to I need to use?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->CGFloat
{
    let cell:DetailCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as DetailCell // ????????

    var height:CGFloat = 84.0;

    if ("toggel on"){
        height = 84.0;
    }
    else{
        height = 0.0;
    }

    return height;
}
```

Comment: What is the DetailCell? How do you know that you are working at the correct section?

Answer (score 0):

You don't wanna reload the whole tableView because of one section. I suggest using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(_:withRowAnimation:)` keeping only the first cell so the user will be able to display the rest of the section again. Update your data source as well and use some flag so you know which cell to not display.